# JSP Custom tag with JSF body

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat, custom-tags

I'm tying to create my own template mechanism for a site. I've made 2 custom tags named "TemplateInsert" and "TemplateFor" one would use them like this:

```
<prefix:insert templateFile="someFile>
    <prefix:for name="body">
        some content here
    </prefix:for>

    other prefix:for tags...

</prefix:insert>
```

this works perfectly unless there are JSF tags inside your "content". Server doesn't seem to parse them. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the plethora of reasons why JSP has been succeeded by Facelets as per JSF 2.0 / Java EE 6. JSP offers very little templating capabilities. You can however use Facelets 1.x on JSF 1.x if you install it separately as per their [docbook](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html).

Facelets offers exactly your functional requirement already out the box. An example:

`template.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ui:insert name="body" />
    </body>  
</html>
```

`page.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <ui:define name="title">Page title</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:outputText value="JSF tags just work here." />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I'd say, go for Facelets as JSF view technology instead of reinventing one based on JSP.